# В проекте С++ при написании кода сортировки слиянием выдает предупреждение об ошибке С6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer

Tags: c++

Написал сортировку слиянием. Программа компилируется, все работает, но постоянно выдает предупреждение об ошибке  С6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer. Объясните пожалуйста, почему она возникает именно в этих местах(ниже приложу фото кода), ведь не может для разыменования туда попадать нулевой указатель. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
 template <typename T>
void Merge(vector<T>& a, int first, int last) {
    int middle = (first + last) / 2;
    int start = first;
    int index = first;
    int finish = middle + 1;
    if (a[middle] < a[(size_t)middle + 1])
        return;
    int size = last - first + 1;
    vector<T> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(size);
    /*T* tmp;
    tmp = (T*)malloc((size) * sizeof(T));
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        throw "ups"; 
    }*/
    
    while (start <= middle && finish <= last) {
        if (a[start] <= a[finish]) {
            tmp.push_back(a[start]);
            //tmp[index - first] = a[start];
            //*(tmp + index - first) = a[start];
            start++;
            index++;
        }
        else {
            tmp.push_back(a[finish]);
            //tmp[index - first] = a[finish];
            //*(tmp + index - first) = a[finish];
            finish++;
            index++;
        }
    }

    while (start <= middle) {
        tmp.push_back(a[start]);
        //tmp[index - first] = a[start];
        //*(tmp + index - first) = a[start];
        start++;
        index++;
    }

    while (finish <= last) {
        tmp.push_back(a[finish]);
        //tmp[index - first] = a[finish];
        //*(tmp + index - first) = a[finish];
        finish++;
        index++;
    }

    for (int i = first; i <= last;i++)
        //a[i] = *(tmp + i - first);
        a[i] = tmp[i - first];
    //a[i] = tmp[i - first];
    //free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: сейчас тебя токсики заминусуют что код скриншотом))

Comment: Я просто хотел показать где именно ошибка) Сейчас добавлю код

Comment: Скриншот можно просто в виде ссылки, а вот текстовый код обязательно нужен, и отметьте в коде место, где выдаёт предупреждение, и точный текст предупреждения (чтобы можно было скопипастить)

Comment: Голосующие за закрытие, а почему вы вообще решили, что код не работает?

Comment: потому что голосующие - "токсики"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ругается, потому что malloc может  неожиданно вернуть nullptr. Просто добавьте проверку на это и завершайте программу

```
tmp = (T*)malloc((size) * sizeof(T));
if (tmp == nullptr) {
    // exit(1);
    throw "ups"; // я знаю, что так не очень, но для примера сойдет
}
```

либо будьте последовательны и используйте new

```
tmp = new T[size];
```

и никаких ругательств. (да, не забудьте о delete [])

Comment: Спасибо! С malloc() теперь не ругается. Но с новым оператором ругается на 46 строку, которую можно увидеть на фотографии (Warning C6001 Using uninitialized memory '*tmp+i-first'.). Не знаете почему?

Comment: потому что `*tmp+i-first` это `(*tmp)+i-first`. Пишите явно `*(tmp+i-first)`. а лучше ёще так `tmp[i-first]` (если я правильно понял Ваш код)

Comment: `*(tmp + i - first)` уже написано (46 строка), но выдается предупреждение.  `tmp[i - first]` работать здесь не будет.

Comment: а почему не будет работать? правило `*(a+b) = a[b] = b[a]` ещё не отменили. Правда это не повлияет на предупреждение

Comment: Да, вы правы. Видимо я его по своей глупости временно отменил) А насчет предупреждения у вас нет догадок?

Comment: я взял и заменил этот malloc на std::vector, потом `[]` заменил на `.at()`, что бы быть уверенным о индексах и не видел никаких ошибок. Но даже просто замена на вектор + `[]` даст более "плюсовый код" и не будет разыменований, которые и приводят к таким ошибкам

Comment: С вектором время работы алгоритма в 2 раза увеличивается в сравнении с массивом указателей. Поэтому я решил использовать malloc.

Comment: может потому, что тестируется дебажная версия?

Comment: Нет. Сейчас проверил даже на всякий случай. Делаю тест для массива 10, 1000, 10000, 1000000. Для всех проигрыш в два раза. Но ведь если использовать вектор, то постоянно будет копирование происходить. Это и влияет на задержку.

Comment: где именно у Вас копирование?

Comment: Как я понимаю, в момент передачи элемента вектора а[] в std:: vector<int> tmp

Comment: покажите пожалуйста код. Без кода очень сложно что то угадать

Comment: Код мне здесь не прикрепить. Весь основной код представлен в вопросе. Чтобы перейти на векторы, я соответственно убрал все указатели и использовал `vector<T> tmp;
 tmp.resize(size);` и `tmp[index - first] = a[start];`

Comment: Вы можете обновить вопрос.

Comment: Обновил. Пробовал разные методы с векторами, результат один

Comment: ну да, в Вашем варианте оно конечно будет немного медленее. вместо `vector<T> tmp; tmp.reserve(size);` пишите `vector<T> tmp(size);` и будет сразу вектор нужного размера. И потом код без push_back, а прямо записывать - элементы то доступны.

Comment: Да я и напрямую записывал уже. Все равно медленно. Скажите, я правильно понимаю, что это из-за копирования в момент передачи элемента вектора а[] в std:: vector<int> tmp? Или из-за чего он настолько медленнее?

Comment: не нужно было старый код удалять.. надо посмотреть в компилятор напильником. К примеру, студия любит добавлять кучу разного проверочного кода и оно конечно будет чуть медленее.